# Weird characters are added when I press alt-tab in vim's insert mode

Tags: vim

Hello Dear Vim Lovers,

The situation is this.

I am editing something in vim. While I am in insert mode, I press alt-tab key to switch to another window. When I return back to vim, I am seeing alt and tab keys were captured by vim and inserted into my text.

It seems like `[O[I[O[I[O[I[O[I`.

I am working in gnome-terminal. I do not recall this behavior in my previous setups. There must be something wrong but I could not figure it out yet. In case anyone knows how to fix it, please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm sort of clueless, but to me the problem would have to be with your 1) OS, 2) UI (xwindows stack), or 3) gnome-terminal.  *One* of those systems should be eating alt-tab so that it doesn't get forwarded to the app in gnome-terminal.  I'm sure vim can be made to swallow alt-tab, but you'll run into other issues, I suspect.  Maybe try on unix.stackexchange or askubuntu (if appropriate)?

Comment: @zzxyz Thank you for your input. I tried to map alt-tab in insert mode to <ESC> but it did not work. It seem it captures Alt and Tab separately.

Comment: Yeah, and I think you could probably map the escape sequence like `\e[0[I` or whatever, but then you still probably run into problems with other shells, emacs, neovim, etc...ps...if you do `sed -n l`, and then hit say...ctrl-right arrow, you should see a sequence...you should *not* see a sequence for alt-tab.  Curious if you do

Comment: Are you using tmux? If so, is the tmux option `'focus-events'` set (look at the output of `$ tmux show-options -s | grep focus`)? Are you using the [vim-tmux-focus-events](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/vim-tmux-focus-events/blob/master/plugin/tmux_focus_events.vim#L45-L46) plugin? If so, what's the output of `:verb nno <f24>` and `:verb nno <f25>`?

Comment: @user938271 Thank you for your comment. The focus-events is on.  The others are set by vim-tmux-focus-events plugin. Do you know any solution for this? `n <F24>       * :silent doautocmd FocusLost %<CR> 
Last set from ~/workshop/dotfiles/vim/bundle/vim-tmux-focus-events/plugin/tmux_focus_events.vim`

`n  <F25>       * :doautocmd FocusGained %<CR>
Last set from ~/workshop/dotfiles/vim/bundle/vim-tmux-focus-events/plugin/tmux_focus_events.vim`

Comment: @ValidusOculus When Vim gains/loses the focus, tmux sends it `Esc [ I`, and `Esc [ O`.
When Vim receives these sequences, it should interpret them as if you had pressed `F24` and `F25`, which should trigger some mappings which invoke some functions to restore the `FocusGained` and `FocusLost` events.
It can only work if the options `<f24>` and `<f25>` have been set correctly. What's the output of `:set <f24>` and `:set <f25>`? It should be `^[[O` and `^[[I`.

Comment: @ValidusOculus Also, what's the output of `:echo &timeout`, `:echo &ttimeout`, `:echo &timeoutlen`, `:echo &ttimeoutlen`? Try adding this command in your `vimrc` and see if it helps: `:set timeout timeoutlen=3000 ttimeoutlen=100`. See `:h ttm`.

Comment: @user938271 In the order that you asked, 1, 0, 3000, 100. I have added timeoutlen and ttimeoutlen but did not help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was running into this problem after remapping `<Esc>` to a noop as recommended [here](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/10.html). Deleting the remap stopped the characters from being inserted.